# How to make object repository with Windows Elements in appium

Tags: selenium, appium, winappdriver

I recently switched roles from building in selenium for web based applications over  to building automation with Appium/WinAppDriver for windows desktop applications.

On the selenium side I always used a specific structure to build out page objects / actions. Below would live in an "Object Repository" class and would list all of my objects by page.

```
public static By SubmitBtn = By.Id("submit");
```

Then I would create methods that would take one of those object as an input. Here is a simplified method i would use as click.

```
        public void Click(By Control)
        {
             TestInitiator.driver.FindElement(Control).Click();
        }
```

Then in my test it would look something like:

```
action.Click(DemoObject.SubmitBtn);
```

I'm wanting to replicate this using Appium to interact with Windows Elements rather than interacting with web elements. Can someone help me with the syntax I would need to create the object repository in the same way had it on the selenium side?

Comment: Your terminology is misleading - I think you mean mobile native app elements instead of "Windows" elements.  It's done basically the same way, the Appium Driver has the same basic idea for page factory, but the wording is a little different and the xpaths are very different (for native apps).  You'll use things like `MobileElement` `@AndroidFindBy` and `AppiumDriver`.  If you look, you can find many examples.

Comment: @BillHileman I am not testing mobile. I am testing windows desktop applications.

Comment: Selenium interacts with the web browser only. [Coded UI Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code?view=vs-2019) are a good option, but it requires a more expensive license for Visual Studio.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt, Coded UI Tests will be deprecated in the future. Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise will be the last version supporting Coded UI Tests. Winappdriver has been suggested by Microsoft itself, as a replacement for Coded UI.

Comment: @PixelPlex: That's good to know.

Comment: I believe WinAppDriver is not maintained enough to be used, not sure what are other options. As said by @BillHileman all the coding remains same as appium is also build on same architecture as selenium, just in desired cap you will change so that appium will test desktop application, you can give kickstart first with calculator application. You can first try this for java [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/Java/CalculatorTest) and this for c# [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/tree/master/Samples/C%23/CalculatorTest)